# jquery selector not working in Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail, greasemonkey

I'm using Jquery to modify the Google navigation toolbar (the black one).

This selector works on google.com and some other google sites like Google Plus (plus.google.com):

```
$("#gbzc").find("li.gbt")
```

(this selects the li items in the toolbar)

But for some reason, inside gmail, this selector doesn't work. The structure of the page seems exactly the same on gmail.com and in the other google sites, but this selector doesn't return anything when run in gmail.

Any ideas?

Comment: No errors? Maybe conflicting with other js frameworks? Did you try jQuery("selector")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents(including the toolbar) of Gmail unlike other google-pages are loaded within an iframe.

So when you use this code from the top-document you must pass the iframe-document as context(2nd argument for **`$()`** )

Comment: Yes you are right, in Gmail it's in an iframe. I ended up using this if the user is on Gmail: $("#canvas_frame").contents().find("#gbzc"); Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's true that it is because of iframe.

Here is a work around if you are ok to use pure javascript.
You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` function of javascript and it will be able to select whatever you need.

It works fine in gmail. Even `document.getElementsByClassName()` doesn't work.